# Sharing a defined global variable in a header amongst two cpp files

Tags: c++, header, global-variables, extern

I am interested in being able to share a defined global variable across two cpp files. Is the following possible? I am interested in this to avoid having to initialize the global shared variable multiple times. I am having trouble being able to build this code. How would you recommend to declare/define myMap in this case?

**MapHeader.h**

```
#ifndef _MAP_HEADER_
#define _MAP_HEADER_

    #include <string>
    #include <map>
    using namespace std;

    extern const map<int, string> myMap = {{100 , "one hundred"}, {200,"two hundred"}, {300,"three hundred"}};

#endif // _MAP_HEADER_
```

**FirstFile.h**

```
#ifndef _FIRST_FILE_
#define _FIRST_FILE_

    #include "MapHeader.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void myFunction1();

#endif
```

**FirstFile.cpp**

```
#include "FirstFile.h"

void myFunction1(){
    cout << "myFunction1()" << myMap[100] << endl;
}
```

**SecondFile.h**

```
#ifndef _SECOND_FILE_
#define _SECOND_FILE_

    #include "MapHeader.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void myFunction2();

#endif
```

**SecondFile.cpp**

```
#include "SecondFile.h"

void myFunction2(){
    cout << "myFunction2()" << myMap[200] << endl;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "FirstFile.h"
#include "SecondFile.h"

int main()
{
    myFunction1();
    myFunction2();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error message:

> error: passing 'const std::map<>' as 'this' argument of 'std:map<>' .....

Comment: `extern const`, and for heaven't sake no `abusing namespace std` in a header file!

Comment: Hi Kerrek. Thanks for the comment. I am still having some trouble. So, I added only "extern" and got the error "redefinition of 'map'. Then I added "extern const" and got the error "error: passing 'const map' as 'this' argument of 'map'.

Comment: I updated my original post

Comment: Please change your design to remove global variables.  File scope static is better than global.  Search the web for "Why no global variables".

Comment: The initializer has to go with the definition, not the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MapHeader.h, change your definition to extern map myMap; and then move your definition exactly as you had it in MapHeader.h into *one* of the .cpp's.

Comment: Hi sarah. Thanks for your comment. I updated the original post to show the code that I am using

Comment: Does the global variable *have to* be defined in a cpp file? Is it possible to define a global variable in the header file?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the file name doesn't matter, .cpp, .h, .hpp, whatever you like, but it must be defined in one place and only one place (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). defining it in an .h file risks violating the rule as soon as the .h gets included into more than one .cpp

Comment: Thank you Sarah. I decided to make a common.cpp to "define it" and used common.h to declare it as "extern map myMap;". This appears to fixed the problem. Thank you!